# Is copy constructor execute when the function is return-by-value?

Tags: c++

Here I try to use array of objects and wanted to see how they construct and destruct. I have overloaded assignment operator of return type is call-by-value so the value have to copied by using copy constructor. I have my own copy constructor but it won't executing copy constructor but the object is destruct why??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class my
{
int i;
public:
    my(){
        cout<<"Constructor\n";
    }
    my(int a):i(a){
        cout<<"Parameterized Constructor\n";
    }
    my(my& m)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor...........\n";
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    ~my()
    {cout<<"Destructor\n";
    }
    my operator=(const my& m)
    {
        i=m.i;
        cout<<"Overloading Assignment Operator\n";
    }

};
main()
{
my *array=new my[2];//calls constructor 2times

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    array[i]=my(i+10);//overloading assignment operator
    cout<<"END\n\n";
}
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    array[i].display();
}
delete [] array;    
}
```

output:

```
Constructor
Constructor
//for 
Parameterized Constructor
Overloading Assignment Operator
Destructor
Destructor
END

Parameterized Constructor
Overloading Assignment Operator
Destructor

calling of destructor without constructing.
Destructor
END

10
11
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: `my(my& m)` is not a copy constructor. Please review the chapter in your C++ textbook that gives examples of copy constructors, and see if you can tell a major difference between how they are declared and how your not-copy constructor gets declared. Furthermore, even if you have a valid copy constructor when it comes to function return values your compiler is allowed (or sometimes required) to elide the copy, depending on your C++ version. This is not a straightforward topic.

Comment: Your assignment operator doesn't have return operator, so it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings. They are the first line of defence against logic errors. If your code is not generating warnings, check your compiler's documentation for how to turn up the compiler warning level. Turn up the warning level, and then resolve the warnings. Once the warning are taken care of, you may or may not see the results you are expecting .As Sam says above, it gets complicated.

Comment: As for your quesiton title: You may consider that a _move_ constructor would be called when returning a non intrinsic type by value. You should read up about _**R**eturn **V**alue **O**ptimization_.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you elaborate why `my(my& m)` could not be a copy constructor?

Comment: Because it is not. That's not what a copy constructor is. A copy constructor does not take a reference to an object as its parameter. A copy constructor's parameter is something else. See your C++ textbook for specific examples.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you are implying that the parameter has to be `const`, [I don't think that is a requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: @M.A -- which one of the three valid syntaxes for the copy constructors, on that reference page, does not have the `const` keyword?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree that you *should* almost always use `const`, but as stated previously, it is not a requirement for it to be a copy constructor. As quoted from the standard: `A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, ...` [link](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor).

Comment: There is no `return` statement anywhere in your code. How can there be "return by value"?

Comment: @M.A -- A copy constructor must be passed as call-by-reference if not it leads to infinite loop. And it may be const or may not be const. Its our intend to change the reference object data members.

Comment: @NikosC. yes I don't return anything but I mentioned "my" in function return type which indicates "return-by-value", the temporary object got destruct without construct how?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is allowed to avoid creating temporary objects for return values, even if they have side effects.